# Mortar / Flow samples NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mortar.MortarDemoApplication$1

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, dagger, mortar

I'm having a really hard time getting the Mortar/Flow examples working via Eclipse & Maven.

My `.apt_generated` folder is created and there are numerous generated classes in that directory but `MortarDemoApplication$1` is not generated for some reason.

I've gone through numerous examples and other threads troubleshooting this problem, but can't seem to find any solution that works.

I have Annotation Processing enabled in Eclipse, and I've configured the Factory path to include dagger, dagger-compiler, and javawriter. I've read that this should not be necessary as the Eclipse m2e-apt plugin is supposed to handle this, but that seems to be the only way that I could get the `.apt_generated` sources to be generated.

Is there a definitive set of instructions somewhere that perhaps I'm missing?

**UPDATE 1**

Building and running with just Maven from the command line (no Eclipse) presents its own set of issues.

First, the latest Maven 3.2.5 throws the following error when attempting to run `mvn install` from the mortar directory:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/aether/spi/connector/Transfer$State
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.Transfer$State
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 5 more
```

After switching back to Maven 3.1.1 `mvn deploy` works, but the mortar-helloworld app crashes when running it via `mvn android:run` with the following error via logcat:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 2820): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 2820): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 2820): CheckJNI is ON
E/memtrack( 2820): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug( 2820): failed to load memtrack module: -2
D/AndroidRuntime( 2820): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
D/AndroidRuntime( 2820): Shutting down VM
I/ActivityManager( 1315): Start proc com.example.hellomortar for activity com.example.hellomortar/.HelloActivity: pid=2831 uid=10057 gids={50057, 9997} abi=x86_64
E/art     ( 2831): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
I/art     ( 2831): Debugger is no longer active
D/AndroidRuntime( 2831): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831): Process: com.example.hellomortar, PID: 2831
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lmortar/Mortar;
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at com.example.hellomortar.HelloApplication.onCreate(HelloApplication.java:29)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mortar.Mortar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellomortar-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    ... 12 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mortar.Mortar
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):        ... 13 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 2831):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
W/ActivityManager( 1315):   Force finishing activity com.example.hellomortar/.HelloActivity
D/gralloc (  948): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
E/libEGL  (  948): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/SurfaceFlinger(  948): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1332776638
E/SurfaceFlinger(  948): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
W/WindowManager( 1315): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (800x1280) to layer 22010
E/ActivityManager( 1315): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 420x420
W/ActivityManager( 1315): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{515bd0e u0 com.example.hellomortar/.HelloActivity t20 f}
W/ActivityManager( 1315): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{515bd0e u0 com.example.hellomortar/.HelloActivity t20 f}
D/TaskPersister( 1315): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=20_task.xml
W/BatteryStatsImpl( 1315): Couldn't get kernel wake lock stats
I/Process ( 2831): Sending signal. PID: 2831 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Are you using third party library project or added any jar file?

Comment: No, the only dependencies are the ones included as Maven Dependencies.

Comment: I also have the same error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.Transfer$State when building with Maven 3.2.5 Do we really have to switch to an older version ?

Comment: The error does not happen when switching back to Maven 3.2.3